# Android Toolbar menu icon color

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Как изменить цвет иконки меню в Toolbar API 15(не те иконки которые находятся в пунктах меня, а та иконка которая это меню вызывает)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В стилях за это (и кое что ещё) отвечает аттрибут

```
colorControlNormal
```

Comment: это api21. мне нужно api 15

Comment: @Mikalai, просто не пишите `android:` до имени аттрибута.